# Dynamically selecting one particular array from string.xml

Tags: android, arrays, autocomplete, filtering

Created an app where there are two AutoCompleteTextViews. In the first user enters the kind of food he/she would like. Ex: Italian, Chinese, etc.

If suppose the user enters Chinese in the 1st AutoCompleteTextView, the 2nd AutoCompleteTextView should suggest only Chinese food items. In the strings.xml, I have created one array named "tastes" that contains the different tastes like Italian, Chinese, etc. Then I have one array named "Italian" which contains only Italian dishes, like wise an array named "Chinese" which contains only Chinese dishes and so on.

If once the user enters his choice in the 1st textview, how do I select the corresponding array from strings.xml for the 2nd textview?

What can I use other than swicth case?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find);

    this.text1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.taste);
     String[] tastes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tastes); 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTaste = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, taste);
    this.text1.setAdapter(adapterTaste);
    this.text1.setThreshold(1);



     this.text2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.item);
     String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Chinese);
     // In place of Chinese in the above line, the feed from text1 ie users choice. 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterItem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
    this.text2.setAdapter(adapterItem);
    this.text2.setThreshold(1);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setOnItemSelectedListener()` is the method you are looking for.

In your case you would be having your source code as,

```
text1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        // Use the position to get which item was selected i.e Chinese or Italian
        // Create an adapter for the second AutoComplete
        // Set the adapter for second AutoCompleteTextView
    }
});
```

[Method Documented here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29)
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the particular approach, could you please kindly suggest how to set the adaptor as the arrays are already defined in string.xml.